# Probability in Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, normal-distribution

I've a question here. Basically I have the mean and standard deviation of a variable (IQ). I want to find the probability that 8 out of 10 people randomly selected have IQ scores between 85.0 and 122.5.

I also have the following information worked out:

- mean = 100
- standard distribution = 15
- n = 10
- p = 0.7745

Should I be using Poisson to do this?

Appreciate any directions and advice please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) Work out the probability that a single person has an IQ in the range given. You need to make an assumption about the distribution of IQ.

> Use the cumulative distribution function for the two end points of the range to calculate the probability of someone's falling between them. Call it $\pi$.

(2) Work out the probability that 8 out of 10 people have an IQ in the range given. You likely want to assume that 'randomly selected' implies independently.

> Then you're looking for the probability of an event's occurring in 8 out of 10 independent trials when it has probability $\pi$ of occurring in a single trial. (This phrasing should suggest a suitable distribution.)

Comment: The assumption I made is that it follows a normal distribution. In this case do I still use CDF?

Comment: Yes, the normal CDF.

Comment: am i right to say that the distribution to be used for the second part is poisson?

Comment: (1) Perhaps [NIST](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda362.htm#CDF) or [IPSUR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IPSUR/vignettes/IPSUR.pdf). (2) The number of events in ten trials can't have a Poisson distribution because you can't get more than ten out of ten whereas a Poisson variable is unbounded above.

Comment: will it be something along the lines of this? http://picpaste.com/pics/photo-oW0vq7VO.1392654021.jpg

Comment: One thing I find really strange is that we are not able to meet the requirement where np and np(1-p) are both 5 or greater.

Comment: You're on the right track: use the binomial distribution. But you don't need to approximate it: use the [exact formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function).

Comment: am i right to say i do P(x=8) + P(x=9) + P(x=10) ?

Comment: A literal reading of your question suggests $\pr(X=8)$ is the answer, but if you meant '8 or more', then yes.